# Automatically prefix columns with the same name in a select

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

How could one easily select from tables that contain columns with the same name? Conflicting names in a CTE for example are not allowed. Is there a way to for example automatically rename all of the columns as TableName_ColumnName? Having to write out all of the columns just for this is very impractical.

Comment: Provide the code that you have tried.

Comment: One requirements of relational model theory is that one set of column names should be unique (especially according to view/derived tables/cte). You can try alias tables for example table1 t1, table2 t2 and use t1.*, t2.* but this not solve duplicated names problem